# Шрифт и семейство шрифтов. Как понять где что?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Я понимаю, что семейство шрифтов (оно же гарнитура) содержит в себе шрифты. Но как это все на практике мне непонятно. Например, есть семейство шрифтов `Times`. Оно содержит себе какие-то шрифты. Также у нас есть `Times New Roman`. Что это? Шрифт или семейство шрифтов? Логично было бы сказать, что это шрифт, который содержится в семействе шрифтов `Times`. Но если посмотреть на определение что такое шрифт, то...

> ...шрифт определяет свойства конкретного члена семейства шрифтов, например, полужирное или курсивное начертание, в то время как гарнитура определяет согласованный стиль семейства шрифтов.[Источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#:%7E:text=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%B2,%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2.)

...теперь больше похоже на то, что `Times New Roman` - это семейство шрифтов. Если, например, заглянуть в тот же [Google Fonts](https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/times-new-roman?QueryFontType=Web&src=GoogleWebFonts), то можно увидеть, что тут есть много разных начертаний, вариантов того, как отображается `Times New Roman`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо же эти все варианты `Times New Roman` являются стилями шрифта?

Comment: Times и Times New Roman это два разных семейства. Хотя и очень похожих, просто потому что оба срисовывались с газеты The Times.

Comment: Шрифт это одно конкретное начертание. Например у вас на картинке Times New Roman Medium Italic это один шрифт. Семейством называют несколько шрифтов. В обычной жизни часто говорят просто «шрифт» имея в виду семейство. Например «Этот документ набран шрифтом Arial», хотя в реальности в документе несколько начертаний — заголовки полужирные, цитаты выделены италиком и т.п.

Comment: @Alexey Ten ага, понятно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, ***Times New Roman* - семейство шрифтов**, в котором содержится обычное, курсивное, полужирное и другие начертания.